# Pymongo - how to get status as a python dictionary for rep sets

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to mongo and I am using pymongo. I am finding the documentation for pymongo to be all over the place.

1) I have a rep set. From the mongo shell, if I run the below I get what I need.

```
sudo mongo 111.111.111.111 --eval "printjson(rs.status())"
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
connecting to: 111.111.111.111/test
{
    "set" : "hey",
    "date" : ISODate("2012-11-10T11:47:58Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "111.111.111.111:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 69189,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1352478921000, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2012-11-09T16:35:21Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I need to get that info from pymongo.

1) I connect to the primary. I get `none` but per the above that node is primary:

```
c = ReplicaSetConnection("111.111.111.111:27017", replicaSet='heythat')
print c.primary
None
```

2) I want to run `c.command("status")` but that operation is not supported.

So, how to I use pymongo to return the primary and also to return status as a Python dictionary?

Answer (score 12):

`rs.status()` calls the 'replSetGetStatus' admin command, in python you can do that like so:

```
conn = ReplicaSetConnection("111.111.111.111:27017", replicaSet='heythat')
conn.admin.command('replSetGetStatus')
```

Protip: If you want to know what command a shell helper calls, then leave the brackets off the function to see the code eg:

```
heythat:PRIMARY> rs.status
function () {
    return db._adminCommand("replSetGetStatus");
}
```